# R returnValue not working in on.exit when using bquote

Tags: r, devtools

While working with the new R 3.2.0 function `returnValue` I've found a behavior which might be unwanted behavior, if even not a bug.

It seems that `returnValue` will not work if it is wrapped inside `eval(bquote(on.exit(`. See below.

1. working as should works - not using `eval(bquote(on.exit(`

```
f <- function(x, case = 0L){
  pt <- proc.time()[[3L]]
  on.exit(message(paste("elapsed:",round(proc.time()[[3L]]-pt,4),"\nclass:",class(returnValue())[1L])))
  Sys.sleep(0.001)
  if(case==1L) rcol <- "a"
  else if(case==2L) rcol <- "b"
  else if(case==3L){
    pt <- 100
    x$a <- x$a + pt
    rcol <- "a"
  } else return(x)
  return(x[[rcol]])
}
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
f(df, case=0L) # OK: expected
# elapsed: 0.001 
# class: data.frame
#   a b
# 1 1 a
# 2 2 b
# 3 3 c
f(df, case=1L) # OK: expected
# elapsed: 0.002 
# class: integer
# [1] 1 2 3
f(df, case=2L) # OK: expected
# elapsed: 0.002 
# class: character
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
f(df, case=3L) # HMMM?: not expected but still correct
# elapsed: 589.695 
# class: numeric
# [1] 101 102 103
```

On the `case=3L` we may get unexpected results because `pt` variable was overwrite during processing. Still this is not an issue because it works as it should. Yet we want to handle such cases without relaying on the variable names, that's why using `bquote` below.

2. `returnValue` always returning NULL if wrapped into `eval(bquote(on.exit(`

```
f <- function(x, case = 0L){
  pt <- proc.time()[[3L]]
  eval(bquote(on.exit(message(paste("elapsed:",round(proc.time()[[3L]]-.(pt),4),"\nclass:",class(returnValue())[1L])))))
  Sys.sleep(0.001)
  if(case==1L) rcol <- "a"
  else if(case==2L) rcol <- "b"
  else if(case==3L){
    pt <- 100
    x$a <- x$a + pt
    rcol <- "a"
  } else return(x)
  return(x[[rcol]])
}
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
f(df, case=0L)
# elapsed: 0.002 
# class: NULL
#   a b
# 1 1 a
# 2 2 b
# 3 3 c
f(df, case=1L)
# elapsed: 0 
# class: NULL
# [1] 1 2 3
f(df, case=2L)
# elapsed: NULL 
# class: character
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
f(df, case=3L)
# elapsed: 0.001 
# class: NULL
# [1] 101 102 103
```

I assume it shouldn't work like that.
How can I avoid such behavior and substitute values within unevaluated expression in `on.exit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on.exit()` is just delaying expression evaluation. It isn't storing the value of `pt` at the time it's created because it is not evaluated at the time it's run. If you want to "protect" a value, you need to create your own scope. A function can have it's own scope. For example:

```
f <- function(x, case = 0L){
  eptime <- local({start = proc.time()[[3L]]; function() proc.time()[[3L]]-start})
  on.exit(message(paste("elapsed:",round(eptime(),4),"\nclass:",class(returnValue())[1L])))
  ...
}
```

So here we replace the function variable `pt` with a function named `eptime`.

The `eval(bquote())` forces execution of the `returnValue()` immediately, not at the end of the function. You're not getting the delayed evaluation that you want. See

```
f <- function(x) {
    eval(bquote(on.exit(print(paste("exit", .(x))))))
    x<-"ok"
    print(paste("return",x))
}
f("apple")
# [1] "exit apple"
# [1] "return ok"
```

such that your exit code runs first. This is not unique to `returnValue()`.